# Firebase messaging, send notification only once

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin

How do I send a notification only one with Firebase messaging? I am sending a notification when a certain condition is true. For example if `x` is equal to `y`. The problem is that this condition can be true for an x amount of time. This will cause the application to keep sending the notification whilst the condition is still true. Therefore, I would like to know a method how I can check if the message is for example unique, and send each notification only once. This is my code (with the example condition):

```
if(x == (2*y))
{
    SendNotification("", x.ToString(), y.ToString());
}

string SendNotification(string DeviceToken, string title, string msg)
{
    var result = "-1";
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", serverKey));
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    var payload = new
    {
        to = "/topics/",
        priority = "high",
        content_available = true,
        notification = new
        {
            body = msg,
            title = title
        },
    };
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = serializer.Serialize(payload);
        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
    }
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that there could be 2 unique notifications right after each other with different x and y values. So creating a boolean to check wheter a notification is sent, will not work.

Comment: **I am sending a notification when a certain condition is true.**, what does it means? What is certain condition?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT sorry I forgot to put the example in the code. This is just an example with `if(x == y)`. I updated the code.

Comment: Anyone an idea?

Comment: If you want to check whether a notification is sent, you can go to check if having response, According to your description, I guess that you have two condition, and different condition to send different notification?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this question is not about Xamarin at all.

You send notification from your server application, right? So if you know that you need to send notification only once when `x == y` then set a boolean flag for example. Or create a `state` and keep it in database.